# faraday's rotation for revealing hidden text

Tags: optics, experimental-physics

I'm trying to come up with a twist on the known faraday's rotation experiment involving a laser projecting into a polarizer. the polarized light then passes in a selenoid containing a glass rod. the magnetic field in the selenoid causes a rotation of the polarized light ,going out  and passing through another polarizer.

Now, My aim is to use this experiment to reveal a hidden text.
What I was thinking of,  prior to activating the magnetic field, my input and output polarizers will be 90 degrees to each other (exstinction angle), blocking all light. now, naturally after somedegree of rotation (I dont care about the angle, I just need to see the text coming out, naturally with lower intensity) when magnetic field is active, Some light should pass trough the output polarizer. my question is, how can i modify the experiment to do this, I would naturally need to replace the laser light source with a flashlight with a piece of cellophane I wrote the text on. will this work with a flashlight?

any tips will be appreciated!! 
thanks

Comment: Hint: Faraday didn't have a laser. :-)

Comment: indeed he didn't:) but I'm wondering , given my glass tube is fairly small in diameter, I would need a flash light with the same diameter coated with the cellophane the text is written on in order to see anything right? just trying to logistically work it in my head

Comment: Why are you bothering with a solenoid to begin with? You can buy 1-1.5T permanent magnets for pennies these days. Making a 1T electromagnet is a real pain in the bum. If you want to play around with the Faraday effect any which way, do it the easy way.

Comment: Ho, Good idea, but do these come in a hollow tube form? as i still need to put the glass rod inside to get the rotation going

Comment: Try this page for a simple setup with two magnets: http://massey.dur.ac.uk/research/slowlight/slowlightgallery.html

Comment: thanks, so i just slide the glass rod inside the hole in the magnets ?

Comment: Pretty much. I can't tell you how well it will work, but the magnetic field does not have to be homogeneous, so it should work OK.

Comment: thanks for the help,I'll look into it, if it does work with magnets it will save alot of headache dealing with power supplies and selenoids